# Quantum Circuit Alignment

Tags: vertical-alignment, circuits

I have prepared the following

```
\begin{equation}
\Qcircuit @C=1em @R=.7em {
& \gate{H} & \ctrl{1} & \gate{H} & \qw \\
& \gate{H} & \targ & \gate{H} & \qw }= \Qcircuit @C=1em @R=.7em {
& \targ & \qw \\
& \ctrl{-1} & \qw
}
\end{equation}
```

which outputs the correct circuit. However, the equals sign is aligned with the top wire in the circuit. I'd like to align the equals sign in the middle of the circuits to improve the aesthetics. Could someone show how this is implemented?

For clarity I include a picture of the output, so that the current alignment can be visualized
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use only one circuit. From the documentation we have

```
\Qcircuit @C=.5em @R=0em @!R {
& \ctrl{1} & \qw & & & \qw & \ctrl{1} & \qw &
\ctrl{1} & \ctrl{2} & \qw\\
& \ctrl{1} & \qw &
\push{\rule{.3em}{0em}=\rule{.3em}{0em}} & &
\ctrl{1} & \targ & \ctrl{1} & \targ & \qw &
\qw\\
& \gate{U} & \qw & & & \gate{V} & \qw &
\gate{V^\dag} & \qw & \gate{V} & \qw
}
```

producing

[image]

So you can adapt to your case.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
$$
\Qcircuit @C=1em @R=.7em {
   & \gate{H} & \ctrl{1}  & \gate{H} & \qw  & \raisebox{-2.2em}{=}  & & \targ & \qw \\
   & \gate{H} & \targ  & \gate{H} & \qw & & & \ctrl{-1} & \qw 
}   
$$
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Since you seem to have understood what packages are needed, you can improve your answer by making it into a complete compilable example (the question itself doesn't give many clues about what's necessary). Please, remind that `$$` is deprecated in LaTeX, see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)